# Publishing WebServices directly from Databases

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, postgresql, salesforce

Hello,
                        I have read some where we can publish web-services directly from databases i.e applications can make http calls to databases directly and retrieve data from web-services. Is it really possible... i have searched in internet but haven't found anything much useful...

I have a  requirement that i want to connect Salesforce to oracle or PostgreSQL databases and has to retriew data.Initially i planned like creating a web-service in java to connect to dtabase and retriew data and sending that data to salesforce as web-service response... But have thinking is it possible to create web-services on databases it self so that external applications can connect to databases using http calls.. Because in Salesforce there is no option to connect to external databases directly..

I have searched a lot but haven't find any strong point's..hoping some one could guide me on this

Comment: thank you... got answer from below post.. i have narrowed my need in below comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. However, databases that support webservices directly are (AFAIK) all NOSQL type solutions. For example, [apache couchdb](http://couchdb.apache.org/) has a wiki on [HTTP_database_API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_database_API) and it documents

1. [List Databases](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_database_API#List_Databases)
2. [PUT (Create New Database)](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_database_API#PUT_.28Create_New_Database.29)
3. [DELETE](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_database_API#DELETE)

And other operations. Another example is [OrientDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OrientDB) the wikipedia entry states that it is *Web ready: supports natively HTTP, RESTful protocol and JSON without use 3rd party libraries and components.*

Alternatively, you might implement your own middle-ware layer of web-services to connect to any other database.

Comment: thank you.. is it possible in PostgreSQL databases...

Comment: There is an [early draft proposal](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/HTTP_API); you could still write your own middle-ware solution.

Comment: It was an early draft solution,presently  is it functional... i.e can i use that api now... @ Elliott Frisch

Comment: @rajasekhar No, it's an early draft **proposal**; as in no one has written it yet.

Comment: @ Elliott Frisch mean i cannot access the database directly with http calls,without writing any external web services...

Comment: You can write your own web service wrapper around your postgres database. Other options include using a different database.

Comment: If possible can you give me some example links... for web service wrapper around our postgres database.I was completely new to web-services..  @Elliott Frisch

Comment: Do you know how to connect to a postgres database? Do you know how to write a web service? No, I can't give you example links to how to do those two things at the same time (if I could your solution would already be implemented).

Comment: yaa i know how to connect to databases ... and writing web services in java... but haven't write any webservice directly on databases... any how thanks for the details....